# ASP.Net v4.0 and ASP.Net v4.0 classic missing in IIS Application Pool list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I do not find `ASP.NET v4.0` and `ASP.NET v4.0 classic` in IIS.

I have tried below:

1) Installing ASP.Net

[image: ASP.NET 4.5]

2) Run `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` in command prompt as administrator

3) Run `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all` in command prompt as administrator

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From where cannot you find them? Make that part clear please.

Comment: @LexLi, Thanks for pointing! It's missing in the Application Pool list in IIS